# Having issue in connection string of already an open DataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

I m facing this issue when same person open the same page at same time on different system.
I have searched a lot on this but found no successful solution.

I have tired :

1. `MultipleActiveResultSets = true` in connection string
2. Increasing Connection waiting time
3. Verified all connection are closed

This issue comes only when above condition created. Kindly let me know solution which really works

this my connection function which i m using

```
public DataSet SelectDs(string str)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConStr;
        con.Open();
    }

    cmd.CommandText = str;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 12000;
    adpt.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adpt.Fill(ds);

    con.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Probably if you add a bit of code where the issue happens you will get more chances to get a precise answer.

Comment: can you share some code where you get this error?

Comment: @AltafSami this happening in all pages i sharing my connection function for dataset

Comment: @Steve  this happening in all pages i sharing my connection function for datase

Comment: @ArjunSharma what is size of number of records returned ??

Comment: @Pratik its not fixed it can ranges from 10 to 10000

Comment: @ArjunSharma So is there is any complex query on `CommandText` which is taking time.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mortal sin to use a global connection object in that way. It is bad (very bad) in WinForms applications, but in ASP.NET is deadly. (as you have discovered)

The usage pattern for a disposable object (and an expensive one like the connection) is

```
CREATE, OPEN, USE, CLOSE, DESTROY
```

The [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) mechanism exist to make easier the usage of this pattern.
Instead you try to work against it and you pay the consequences.

Your code should be rewritten as

```
public DataSet SelectDs(string str)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))  // CREATE
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))         // CREATE
    {
        con.Open();    // OPEN
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 12000;
        using(SqlAdapter adpt = new SqlAdapter(cmd))   // USE
             adpt.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }  // CLOSE & DESTROY 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting inside a Using statement like

```
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{

connection.Open();

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    } // reader closed and disposed up here

   } // command disposed here

 } //connection closed and disposed here
```

Comment: I cannot use it because this will require a major in my connection class I' m using common object

Comment: Then you will have hard times ahead of you

Answer (score 0):

in finally clause use this

```
if (readerObj.IsClosed == false)
{
  readerObj.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also dispose your command object before returning dataset.

try cmd.Dispose() after con.close()